# loversize parameter from lettrine package not working

Tags: lettrine

The `loversize` parameter from the [lettrine](http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/lettrine/doc/lettrine.pdf) package is not working for me. Below is a MWE to illustrate the problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{lettrine}

\begin{document}

\lettrine[loversize=0.5]{T}{his} is a sample of text. This is a sample 
of text. This is a sample of text. This is a sample of text. This is a 
sample of text. This is a sample of text. This is a sample of text. 
This is a sample of text. This is a sample of text. This is a sample 
of text. This is a sample of text. This is a sample of text. This is a 
sample of text. This is a sample of text. This is a sample of text. 
This is a sample of text. This is a sample of text.\\

\end{document}
```

Setting `loversize` equal to any decimal value in the permitted range (from -1 to 1) does not change the dropped capital in any way. Does anybody know why this is the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a scalable font.  By default, TeX uses the Computer Modern fonts, which come in only fixed sizes.  Try adding:

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

This is a scalable copy (mostly identical) of Computer Modern called Latin Modern.  That should take care of your problem.